# RGB to HSV using colorsys

Tags: python, rgb, hsv

i am trying to make a tracking program that takes an image and displays where the the object with the specified color is:

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u202H.jpg

to do this i am using RGB right now but it is realy hard to work with it so i want to convert it into a hue so it is easier to work with. i am trying to use colorsys but after doing some research i have no idea what parameters it wants in and what it gives. i have tried to get a match using colorizer.org but i get some nonsence.

```
>>> import colorsys
>>> colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(45,201,18)
(0.3087431693989071, 0.9104477611940298, 201)
```

alredy the colorsys is not acting as documented because at https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html it says that the output is always a float between 0 and 1, but the value is 201. that also is impossible as in standard HSV the value is between 0 and 100.

my questions are:
what does colorsys expect as an input?
how do i convert the output to standard HSV? (Hue = 0-360, saturation = 0-100, value = 0-100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Coordinates in all of these color spaces are floating point values. In the YIQ space, the Y coordinate is between 0 and 1, but the I and Q coordinates can be positive or negative. In all other spaces, the coordinates are all between 0 and 1.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html

You must scale from [0, 255] to [0, 1], or divide your RGB values with 255. If using python 2 make sure not to do floor division.

---

Here is an example code inspired by [Pillow's `getcolor`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageColor.html#getcolor).

```py
from colorsys import rgb_to_hsv

def to_hsv(r, g, b):
  h, s, v = rgb_to_hsv(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255)
  return int(h * 255), int(s * 255), int(v * 255)
```

```py
rgb = (47, 207, 227)

# This is one usage, which returns (132, 202, 227).
hsv_example_1 = to_hsv(*rgb)

# This is another usage, which returns (132, 202, 227).
hsv_example_2 = to_hsv(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])
```

Comment: thank you. the flooring division was the problem as i am using python 2 on a raspberry pi(the default) and i tried this before but only got 0.0 answers.

Comment: @mateuszdrwal "The default?", there is no such thing as python 2 is my *default python*, as PEP394 says, `python` is expectedly python 2 on all systems *("for the time being, all distributions should ensure that python refers to the same target as python2")*, use `python3` for the preferred Python 3 version. Notably, Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't ship with python 2 any more by default (you must install it manually), but the python 3 interpreter is still called `python3`, and if you then actually install `python-2.7`, then you will get the `/usr/bin/python -> python2.`7 as well.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the thing i ment by "default" is that if i create a .py file on my rpi it will open in IDLE for python 2.7.9 unless i tell it otherwise